# What RegEx would delimit a list which was copied and pasted from a web page?

Tags: php, regex

I have a form which accepts a list of keywords. I then convert the list into an array using `mb_split` in PHP for entry into the database. However, I'm unable to find a RegEx that delimits the list successfully. Users will typically be pasting data that was copied from a list on a web page. Here's what I'm trying:

```
mb_split('/\s+/', $keywords)
```

And here's the result in the database:

```
keyword1¶keyword2¶keyword3
```

I would have thought that the ¶ character would have been considered whitespace covered by `\s+`. I tried handling the ¶ character specifically, but it didn't work:

```
mb_split('/\s+\u00B6/', $keywords)
```

So what RegEx *would* work here?

**SOLUTION**

I ended up using this:

```
mb_split('\n|\r|¶', $keywords)
```

I needed to add the `|` (logical OR) and actually paste the ¶ symbol into the regex. I also switched to using `\n` and `\r` instead of `\s` to avoid losing multi-word entries which involve spaces.

Comment: Try to solve the problem without regex and you'll be glad you did later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is whitespace followed by a ¶ . You need whitespace *or* a ¶ :

```
/(\s|\u00B6)+/
```

The ¶  character is not whitespace because you can see it. It does have semantic meaning as whitespace, but that does not make it whitespace unless the regex engine is looking for such semantics.

Comment: Okay, I added the logical OR but I'm still getting the same result: a single blob of words with a ¶ between each word.

Comment: @David: Can you post some sample input in your question?

Comment: I got it now. Using the OR along with actually pasting the ¶ symbol (instead of using the encoding value) seemed to do the trick. My final code was this: `mb_split('\n|\r|¶', $keywords)` (I'm using `\n` and `\r` instead of `\s` now so that spaces don't get lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just using `¶` works for me.  `mb_split` is different from `preg` in that its regex should not be delimited either.

Comment: I'm not sure which answer to pick - it was a combo of the two that did it!

Comment: @David Waleed answered first, so I think you should pick his.